# Mapbox display tile borders on polygon styled as line

Tags: mapbox, polygon, layer, cartodb

I am trying to display the borders of polygon with some line attributes based on zoom.
The only problem is that on certain zoom levels the borders of tiles are shown.

[image: Polygono a zoom alejado]

[image: Polygono con zoom cercano]

The style that I am using to display this is :

```
{ type: 'line',
'source-layer': 'pluto15v1',
"layout": {
  "line-round-limit": 1,
  "line-cap": "round",
  "line-miter-limit": 0,
  "line-join": "round"
},
"paint": {
    "line-color": [
        "step",
        ["zoom"],
        "hsla(0, 86%, 56%, 0)",
        7,
        "hsla(0, 86%, 56%, 0.58)",
        13,
        "hsl(0, 86%, 56%)",
        22,
        "hsla(0, 86%, 56%, 0.29)"
    ],
    "line-width": [
        "interpolate",
        ["linear"],
        ["zoom"],
        9,
        13,
        16,
        22,
        22,
        22
    ],
    "line-opacity": 0.76
}
```

Comment: Already fixed, the problem was with the buffer size of the tiles, I was using 1, with 8 and up is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your feature geometries are `Polygon`. When they are cut at tile boundaries, you end up with polygons that have an edge along the tile boundary.

If you use feature geometries that are `LineString` instead, then this doesn't happen. At tile boundaries, they are clipped and there is no part along the tile boundary.